# How to assign ES6 class method to a function?

Tags: javascript, function, methods, ecmascript-6

Is there a way to do something like

```
class AppContainer {
    fetch = _.debounce(...) {
    }
}
```

I need to have a class method aliased to the lodash debounce function.

Comment: @torazaburo you can't do that in a class definition unfortunately

Comment: Please, elaborate, do you need `fetch` to be *debounce* function or *debounced* function? What does `_.debounce(...) {
    }` stand for?

Comment: @Tibrogargan Not in a question that doesn't mention Babel anyway :P

Comment: Do you mean a "static" method, in which case it would be `AppContainer.fetch = (...args) => _.debounce(...args);`? Or an instance method, in which case it would be `fetch(...args) { _.debounce(...args); }` inside the class definition?

Comment: Nice ask-and-run. Why post the question if you're not going to respond to requests for clarification from people trying to help you? Your profile says you've been back.

Answer (score 2):

You can define the method separately and then debounce it manually in the constructor, like this:

```
class AppContainer {
  constructor(...args){
    super(...args);
    this.fetch = _.debounce(this.fetchImpl_.bind(this));
  }

  fetchImpl_(){

  }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't that end up with fetch being the result of calling debounce, rather than a reference to the function itself?

Comment: @Tibrogargan Nope. Debouncing presumes that the function will be called multiple times, so `debounce(fn)` should return debounced function without calling it. Lodash follows this practice.

Comment: @estus That's my point.  he's setting fetch to the result of debouncing a function, but fetch should be debounce itself - not the result of debounce.  i.e.  When he calls `fetch` he's expecting his argument to be debounced, not passed as an argument to a function that was already the result of a debounce

Comment: @Tibrogargan It is ok. `debounce(fn)` returns a wrapper for original function. `fetch` will be debounced `fetchImpl_` method. You're confusing `debounce(fn)` with `debounce(fn)()`.

Comment: @estus no sir, I am not.  The OP's original question is perhaps ambiguous.  I was taking his meaning to be literally that he wants to create an alias, i.e.  Calling `anAppContainer.fetch(x)` would literally give the same result as calling `_.debounce(x)`

Comment: @Tibrogargan Hmm, yeah I can't tell now that you mention it. I took the `_.debounce(...)` in the example to mean they wanted to call the function and debounce some existing method, but `class method aliased to the lodash debounce function` seems to contradict that. Gonna leave this for now since it seems more like a real usecase.

Comment: @Tibrogargan Thanks for the explanation. You are correct. I'm positive that there is a mistake in the question and not in the answer. It makes little sense to have something like `this.fetch = _.debounce` for fetching method. A clarification from OP would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Add it to the prototype as you normally would.  Quote:

> JavaScript classes introduced in ECMAScript 6 are syntactical sugar over JavaScript's existing prototype-based inheritance

Demo:

```js
// Define a class using the pre ECMA-6 mechanism
function Wonk(n) {
    this.name = n;
}

// Add a function to the prototype of our pre ECMA-6 class
Wonk.prototype.wonk = function() { console.log( "Funky" ); };

// Create an instance of our pre ECMA-6 class as a stand-in for lodash's _
var wonk = new Wonk();

// Define an ECMA-6 class
class Funky {
    constructor() {
    }
}

// ECMA-6 class definition does not support (this claim needs a reference) adding a function by reference in the definition, so add it with the pre ECMA-6 mechanism
Funky.prototype.foo = wonk.wonk;

// Test the resulting class.
function init() {
    var funky = new Funky();
    funky.foo();
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);
```

Comment: why bother creating an instance of `Wonk`?  You should be able to do `Funky.prototype.foo = Wonk.prototype.wonk`

Comment: No real reason - that should work too.  I did it that way because `wonk` is a stand-in for `_`.  (I don't know how Lodash defines itself.  It could be doing things like `(function() { this.debounce = x => { blah blah blah } }).apply(_)` which would make using the prototype fail)